# Not getting the localstorage token in my react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-toolkit

I have `token.ts` which looks like this -

```
export const contentTypeHeaderWithToken = {
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
  }
};
```

In my reduxtoolkit, I am using this contentTypeHeaderWithToken like this -

```
export const fetchAllRoles = createAsyncThunk<IGetRolesResponse>(
  'user/getroles',
  async (user, {rejectWithValue}) => {
    try {
      const response = await Services.get('/roles', contentTypeHeaderWithToken);
      return response.data.slice().reverse() as IGetRolesResponse;
    } catch(err) {
      const error = err as any;
      return rejectWithValue(error?.response?.data)
    }
  },
);
```

In try statement above, `contentTypeHeaderWithToken` is coming out to be null for the very first time.

Before pulling the token value, I have verified, the token is present in the browser.

[image]

Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: Maybe it's just not stored at the time when `export const contentTypeHeaderWithToken` is evaluated. Try turning this into a function that accesses localStorage and call it in your thunk.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit in the code as how to implement.

Comment: Put a `console.log(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));` in the same module as `contentTypeHeaderWithToken` and also one in `fetchAllRoles`. If my suspicion is correct, the token is just set later at runtime and not present initially.